# Need Guidance on Distributed Cache Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Planning to Configure a farm with 2 Web Front Ends , One Application Server and a Database Server, this is for an internet presence site

I am planning to having the Search Service installed on the App Server.

There is a guidance that DCS should not be configured if the search service is running, so that it leaves with the two WFE's ? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two 'modes' for Distributed Cache -
A collocated mode or a dedicated mode.
The Distributed Cache is started and run on all WFE and APP servers by default. If you have over 10000 users, you should look into a dedicated server (dedicated mode) Distributed Cache. Dedicated Mode simply means all other services are turned off and more memory is allocated to the Distributed Cache.

Based on your topology, it sounds like you should collocate the Distributed cache on your 2 WFE servers (for redundancy) and stop the Distributed Cache Service on the APP server.

Finally, it boils down to memory allocation at the end of the day.

By default the Distributed memory allocation size defaults to a value of 10 percent of total physical memory when SharePoint Server 2013 installs.
You can change the memory allocation with the **Update-SPDistributedCacheSize** cmdlet.

Here is a link that may help on the 'right approach':
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj219572%28office.15%29.aspx
(note the 'Capacity planning for the Distributed Cache service' section).

The Distributed Cache service can be stopped or started via the Central Administration or via PowerShell.

To stop the Distributed Cache service by using Central Administration:
In Central Administration, click Application Management.
In Service Applications, click Manage Services on Server.
On the Services on Server page, locate the Distributed Cache service.
If the Distributed Cache service is started and you want to stop the service, under Action, click Stop.

To stop the Distributed Cache service by using Windows PowerShell:
At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, run the following command:
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($*.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($*.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$serviceInstance.Unprovision()

Comment: On the App Server on Services on Server Can i simply stop the distribution service? or is there any right way to do this?

Comment: Yes, simply stop the service via Central Administration or Poweshell. See above edit.